# fastest way to convert a std::vector to another std::vector

Tags: c++, stl

What is the fastest way (if there is any other) to convert a std::vector from one datatype to another (with the idea to save space)? For example:

```
std::vector<unsigned short> ----> std::vector<bool>
```

we obviously assume that the first vector only contains 0s and 1s. Copying element by element is highly inefficient in case of a really large vector.

Conditional question: 
If you think there is no way to do it faster, is there a complex datatype which actually allows fast conversion from one datatype to another?

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov: The OP wants to save memory. `std::vector<bool>` is specialized to be memory efficient.

Comment: @ R. Martinho Fernandes: You got it!!! I do want magic, unfortainatly std::do_magic() does not seem to exist.

Comment: @Björn, `vector<bool>` is a disaster. Even STL authors admit it was a mistake.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
std::vector<bool>
```

Stop.

A `std::vector<bool>` is... not. `std::vector` has a specialization for the use of the type `bool`, which causes certain changes in the `vector`. Namely, it stops acting like a `std::vector`.

There are certain things that the standard guarantees you can do with a `std::vector`. And `vector<bool>` violates those guarantees. So you should be *very* careful about using them.

Anyway, I'm going to pretend you said `vector<int>` instead of `vector<bool>`, as the latter really complicates things.

> Copying element by element is highly inefficient in case of a really large vector.

Only if you do it wrong.

Vector casting of the type you want needs to be done carefully to be efficient.

If the the source `T` type is convertible to the destination `T`, then this is works just fine:

```
vector<Tnew> vec_new(vec_old.begin(), vec_old.end());
```

Decent implementations should recognize when they've been given random-access iterators and optimize the memory allocation and loop appropriately.

The biggest problem for non-convertible types you'll have for simple types is not doing this:

```
std::vector<int> newVec(oldVec.size());
```

That's bad. That will allocate a buffer of the proper size, but it will *also* fill it with data. Namely, default-constructed `int`s (`int()`).

Instead, you should do this:

```
std::vector<int> newVec;
newVec.reserve(oldVec.size());
```

This reserves capacity equal to the original vector, but it also ensures that no default construction takes place. You can now `push_back` to your hearts content, knowing that you will never cause reallocation in your new vector.

From there, you can just loop over each entry in the old vector, doing the conversion as needed.

Comment: +1 for the vector-bool advice. Until I had a knock-down ... discussion ... here with someone a few days back, I didn't realise how ... questionable ... it was. The trick to get a full capacity vector without constructing any elements is also good. You just may want to consider using `char` as the underlying type rather than `int` (since `int` will be at _least_ as wide as `short`). But assuming that's just an _example_ showing how to copy efficiently, the answer's very good.

Comment: Your answear ist pretty much exactly what i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: -1 for warning about `vector<bool>` instead of suggesting the best and most obvious solution, which is the constructor that takes two iterators. Kibitzing about the details of the example belongs in the comments or at the end of the answer, not as a replacement for the best solution...

Comment: @SteveJessop: Your suggestion requires not only ignoring the dangers inherent in using `vector<bool>`, but it also requires an implicit conversion between the types in question. Which, in this example may be a `bool`, but the OP certainly seemed to suggest went beyond just this example. Writing an implicit conversion is not something to be done for every type.

Comment: `push_back` means the vector needs to increment its endpoint on each iteration of the loop, which isn't needed with `resize`. It's not self-evident that this will be slower than initializing a large region of memory to a primitive value using `memset`. That answer may also depend on the ultimate size of the vector. Best to measure as the OP did if performance is critical.

Answer (score 23):

There's no way to avoid the copy, since a `std::vector<T>` is a distinct
type from `std::vector<U>`, and there's no way for them to share the
memory.  Other than that, it depends on how the data is mapped.  If the
mapping corresponds to an implicit conversion (e.g. `unsigned short` to
`bool`), then simply creating a new vector using the begin and end 
iterators from the old will do the trick:

```
std::vector<bool> newV( oldV.begin(), oldV.end() );
```

If the mapping isn't just an implicit conversion (and this includes
cases where you want to verify things; e.g. that the `unsigned short`
does contain only `0` or `1`), then it gets more complicated.  The
obvious solution would be to use std::transform:

```
std::vector<TargetType> newV;
newV.reserve( oldV.size() );    //  avoids unnecessary reallocations
std::transform( oldV.begin(), oldV.end(),
                std::back_inserter( newV ),
                TranformationObject() );
```

, where `TranformationObject` is a functional object which does the
transformation, e.g.:

```
struct ToBool : public std::unary_function<unsigned short, bool>
{
    bool operator()( unsigned short original ) const
    {
        if ( original != 0 && original != 1 )
            throw Something();
        return original != 0;
    }
};
```

(Note that I'm just using this transformation function as an example.
If the only thing which distinguishes the transformation function from
an implicit conversion is the verification, it might be faster to verify
all of the values in `oldV` first, using `std::for_each`, and then use
the two iterator constructor above.)

Depending on the cost of default constructing the target type, it may be
faster to create the new vector with the correct size, then overwrite
it:

```
std::vector<TargetType> newV( oldV.size() );
std::transform( oldV.begin(), oldV.end(),
                newV.begin(),
                TranformationObject() );
```

Finally, another possibility would be to use a
`boost::transform_iterator`.  Something like:

```
std::vector<TargetType> newV(
    boost::make_transform_iterator( oldV.begin(), TranformationObject() ),
    boost::make_transform_iterator( oldV.end(), TranformationObject() ) );
```

In many ways, this is the solution I prefer; depending on how
`boost::transform_iterator` has been implemented, it could also be the
fastest.

Comment: Thank you very much this was really informative. I wish i could also mark this answear as the right one.

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to use `assign` like this:

```
vector<unsigned short> v;
//...
vector<bool> u;
//...
u.assign(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: You can do this directly in the constructor: `std::vector<bool> u(b.begin(), v.end());`.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: that should be `u(v.begin(), v.end());` I think?

Comment: @Chap: Yes, there is a typo there. The comment is to old to be edited though. Thanks for spotting that.

Answer (score 4):

```
class A{... }
class B{....}
B convert_A_to_B(const A& a){.......}

void convertVector_A_to_B(const vector<A>& va, vector<B>& vb)
{
    vb.clear();
    vb.reserve(va.size());
    std::transform(va.begin(), va.end(), std::back_inserter(vb), convert_A_to_B);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way to do it is to *not* do it. For example, if you know in advance that your items only need a byte for storage, use a byte-size vector to begin with. You'll find it difficult to find a faster way than that :-)

If that's not possible, then just absorb the cost of the conversion. Even if it's a little slow (and that's by no means certain, see [Nicol's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899838/fastest-way-to-convert-a-stdvector-to-another-stdvector/7899924#7899924) for details), it's still necessary. If it wasn't, you would just leave it in the larger-type vector.

Comment: Of course it is better to use the proper datatype from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

First, a warning: Don't do what I'm about to suggest. It's dangerous and must never be done. That said, if you just have to squeeze out a tiny bit more performance No Matter What...

First, there are some caveats. If you don't meet these, you can't do this:

1. The vector must contain plain-old-data. If your type has pointers, or uses a destructor, or needs an operator = to copy correctly ... do not do this.
2. The sizeof() both vector's contained types must be the same. That is, vector< A > can copy from vector< B > only if sizeof(A) == sizeof(B).

Here is a fairly stable method:

```
vector< A > a;
vector< B > b;
a.resize( b.size() );
assert( sizeof(vector< A >::value_type) == sizeof(vector< B >::value_type) );
if( b.size() == 0 )
   a.clear();
else
   memcpy( &(*a.begin()), &(*b.begin()), b.size() * sizeof(B) );
```

This does a very fast, block copy of the memory contained in vector b, directly smashing whatever data you have in vector a. It doesn't call constructors, it doesn't do any safety checking, and it's much faster than any of the other methods given here. An optimizing compiler should be able to match the speed of this in theory, but unless you're using an unusually good one, it won't (I checked with Visual C++ a few years ago, and it wasn't even close).

Also, given these constraints, you could forcibly (via void *) cast one vector type to the other and swap them -- I had a code sample for that, but it started oozing ectoplasm on my screen, so I deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Copying element by element is not highly inefficient. std::vector provides constant access time to any of its elements, hence the operation will be O(n) overall. You will not notice it.

Comment: Just because an operation is O(n) doesn't mean its impact is not noticeable. Or are you using linear lists to store data for random access ?

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifdef VECTOR_H_TYPE1
#ifdef VECTOR_H_TYPE2
#ifdef VECTOR_H_CLASS
/* Other methods can be added as needed, provided they likewise carry out the same operations on both */

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class VECTOR_H_CLASS {
public:
        vector<VECTOR_H_TYPE1> *firstVec;
        vector<VECTOR_H_TYPE2> *secondVec;

        VECTOR_H_CLASS(vector<VECTOR_H_TYPE1> &v1, vector<VECTOR_H_TYPE2> &v2) { firstVec = &v1; secondVec = &v2; }
        ~VECTOR_H_CLASS() {}

        void init() { // Use this to copy a full vector into an empty (or garbage) vector to equalize them
                secondVec->clear();
                for(vector<VECTOR_H_TYPE1>::iterator it = firstVec->begin(); it != firstVec->end(); it++) secondVec->push_back((VECTOR_H_TYPE2)*it);
        }

        void push_back(void *value) {
                firstVec->push_back((VECTOR_H_TYPE1)value);
                secondVec->push_back((VECTOR_H_TYPE2)value);
        }

        void pop_back() {
                firstVec->pop_back();
                secondVec->pop_back();
        }

        void clear() {
                firstVec->clear();
                secondVec->clear();
        }
};
#undef VECTOR_H_CLASS
#endif
#undef VECTOR_H_TYPE2
#endif
#undef VECTOR_H_TYPE1
#endif
```

Comment: Now that I think about it, I wrote this for class and derived class pointers, so it could have limitations if used as a general-purpose tweak.  Sorry!