# std::vector<uchar> to std::vector<char> for opencv mask

Tags: c++

In opencv a function takes a mask array as `std::vector<char>`.
another method returns a `std::vector<uchar>` as a mask.

internally its using the mask to do

```
if(mask[i])
{

}
```

now, is there a way to cast `std::vector<uchar>` to `std::vector<char>` without having to loop over the array and the if statemetn will still hold?

Comment: To help your casting part of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899838/fastest-way-to-convert-a-stdvector-to-another-stdvector

Comment: If you want to do it properly, no. If you want to take the risk, and uchar and char are the same size, and the only values are 0 and 1, then you can try `reinterpret_cast<std::vector<char>&>(mask)` AT YOUR OWN RISK.

Comment: If the performance of the conversion isn't a concern, just writing the code, it's easy to convert. `std::vector<char> v2(v1.begin(), v1.end());` or use `assign` function.