# How to convert a string to uint32_t

Tags: c++, types, casting, io, file-read

I have a program which reads the contents of a file line by line, stores each line into a vector of strings, and then prints the contents of the vector.

After reading the file data into the vector of strings, I am attempting to convert each line from `string` into `uint32`. Each line of the file consists of `32-bit` numbers. An example of the input data file `(input_file.dat)`:

```
31401402
67662718
74620743
54690001
14530874
13263047
84662943
09732679
13839873
```

I would like to convert each of those strings into `uint32_t`, for a different program I have written which converts these numbers into ASCII format (the program **requires** that `uint32_t` is used for conversion).

My program so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

/*
 * Program to iterate through all lines in file and put them in given vector
 *
 */
bool getFileContent(std::string fileName, std::vector<std::string> & vecOfStrs)
{

    // Open the File
    std::ifstream in(fileName.c_str());

    // Check if object is valid
    if(!in)
    {
        std::cerr << "Cannot open the File : "<<fileName<<std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    std::string str;
    // Read the next line from File untill it reaches the end.
    while (std::getline(in, str))
    {
        // Line contains string of length > 0 then save it in vector
        if(str.size() > 0)
            vecOfStrs.push_back(str);
    }
    //Close The File
    in.close();
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    //Store contents in this vector of strings
    std::vector<std::string> vecOfStr;

    // Get the contents of file in a vector
    bool result = getFileContent("input_file.dat", vecOfStr);

    // If above result is true
    if(result)
    {
        // Iterate through the vector contents
        for(std::string & line : vecOfStr)
        {
            //std::cout<<line<<std::endl;      Ignore this print line, it is for debugging only to show that the vector has been correctly filled

            //For each line, convert from string to uint32_t
            std::vector<std::uint32_t>new_variable
            new_variable.assign(vecOfStr.begin(), vecOfStr.end());

        }
    }
}
```

In my above attempt, in the `for` loop underneath the comment which reads "// Iterate through the vector contents", I have attempted to convert each line from a `string` to `uint32_t` using the `vector::assign` function. I did this when researching my problem, and found this function from another SO question: [fastest way to convert a std::vector to another std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899838/fastest-way-to-convert-a-stdvector-to-another-stdvector) (author: Vlad, answered Oct 26 '11 at 7:36). When I try to run this code, I receive the following `error` message:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to ‘unsigned int’ in initialization
```

**TO SUMMARISE:**

How can I read the contents of a file line by line, and convert each line into the data type `uint32_t`? I have ensured that each line is equal to 32-bits.

Comment: [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and friends?

Comment: And to *transform* from a vector of strings to a vector of integers, [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Comment: Or if the numbers is all there is in the file, then [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to copy the data directly from the file into the integer vector.

Comment: What do you mean by *I have ensured that each line is equal to 32-bits.*?  Does each number need to have 32 bits to represent it?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, that is correct.

Comment: So all the number in the file are in the range `[2147483648, 4294967295]`?

Comment: @NathanOliver: The example includes `09732679`.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/q/5590381/560648

Comment: That word `cast` again. What you are attempting to do here is **convert** a string to an integer. There's no cast that will do what you want.

Comment: @john thanks, I have adjusted the title accordingly and have taken your information on board.

Comment: The simplest, in my opinion, would be to not bother with the vector of strings at all and as mentioned use [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to copy directly from the file into the integer vector: `std::vector<uint32_t> intVector(std::istream_iterator<uint32_t>(in), std::istream_iterator<uint32_t>());` That's all you need to read all integers from the file into a vector.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this

```
std::vector<std::uint32_t> new_variable;
for (string str : vecOfStr)
    new_variable.push_back(static_cast<uint32_t>(std::stoul(str)));
```

The `stoul` function converts to string to the integer. Strictly it converts to an `unsigned long` not a `uint32_t`. But all legal values of `uint32_t` can be represented by an `unsigned long` and a cast converts back to the `uint32_t` that you want.

There's other ways (using `std::transform` for instance), but I find an explicit loop to be simpler.

There's no error checking in the code above. If that's necessary something like artm's answer is preferable.

BTW your attempt failed because there's no *implicit conversion* between a `string` and a `uint32_t`. When there is an implicit conversion then what you tried would work.

Comment: `uint32_t > int32_t`.  You'll have overflow issues with this.

Comment: Fixed now I hope.

Comment: The cast is not needed, but its definitely better.

Comment: @NathanOliver warnings, i hate warnings

Comment: One nit pick: `for (string str : vecOfStr)` -> `for (string const& str : vecOfStr)` to avoid copying.

Comment: `for(auto const& str : vecOfStr)` for more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stringstream` for formatting, you'd need to include `<stringstream>`

Also:

- Move `new_variable` outside the loop as otherwise the resulting `vector` would not be useful
- There is no need to pass `vecOfStrs` as reference. Would be better to just return the `vector` by value.

```
        std::vector<std::uint32_t> new_variable;

        for(std::string & line : vecOfStr)
        {
            //For each line, convert from string to uint32_t

            std::stringstream ss(line);
            uint32_t val;
            if( !( ss >> val ) )
            {
                throw std::runtime_error( "failed to convert to uint32" );
            }
            
            std::cout << "val = " << val << '\n';   
            new_variable.push_back( val );
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps vector declaration should be outside the loop

Comment: Original code, but yes, otherwise it'd not be any useful outside that loop.